# UILabel is not centered in my UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, layout, uiview

I'm adding a UILabel to a UIView on initialization and the label will not center itself. I've tried centering it is layoutSubviews and adding constraints programmatically with no luck.  When it appears it is about 200 pixels to the left of the center. Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title andBody:(NSString *)body Andwidth:(CGFloat)width {
self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 60)];
if (self) {

    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 60)];
    containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [self addSubview:containerView];

    self.winningLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 300, 40)];
    self.winningLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.winningLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:30];
    self.winningLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.winningLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    self.winningLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    self.winningLabel.text = @"YOU WIN";
    self.winningLabel.hidden = YES;
    [containerView addSubview:self.winningLabel];

    NSLayoutConstraint *xCenterConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.winningLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    [self addConstraint:xCenterConstraint];

    NSLayoutConstraint *yCenterConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.winningLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    [self addConstraint:yCenterConstraint];

}

    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [self.winningLabel setCenter:self.center];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forget the text alignment. By default the text in a label is aligned to the left. If you want it to be in the center, you should specify it explicitly.

```
self.winningLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```